# No logs on Jhipster-console for Jhipster Application Running in Docker

Tags: docker, kibana, jhipster, docker-machine

When I run Jhipster application on the host and get jhipster-console docker container up, kibana can find logs. However, when I run Jhipster application on prod mode using docker container, kibana cannot find any logs.

I tried to edit application-prod.yml for Jhipster application to use the IP or hostname of my host machine, but still cannot find logs. I am wondering whether this way works for someone. BTW, my host is ubuntu 16 using vagrant.

`logging:
        logstash:
            enabled: true
            host: localhost # If using a Virtual Machine on Mac OS X or Windows with docker-machine, use the Docker's host IP here
            port: 5000
            queueSize: 512`

Comment: need to wait for 3~5 min. up to your application log.

Answer (score 0):

To setup the JHipster Console alongside your application with docker-compose run the docker-compose sub-generator in a separate directory with `jhipster docker-compose`.

When prompted, input your application local directory path and choose the JHipster-Console option. Then simply run `docker-compose up -d` to start everything at once.

Refer to the [JHipster microservices in production documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/microservices-in-production/) for more details